# how to remove systemctl service? (Arch-Linux)

Tags: linux, command-line, arch-linux, systemd, systemctl

Before your flag this as a duplicate question, I have looked through all the questions with the same problem and none of the solutions worked for me.

I was new to installing Arch-linux and was following a shoddy tutorial, in the tutorial, the man explained that I should use:

```
sudo systemctl enable dchpcd@wl01.service
```

so that it automatically starts the wifi service when I boot up, however, I spelled the device name incorrectly, it is actually wlo1 not wl01. Now everytime I boot up, I have to wait 1m 30s for the attempted service start to time out. I tried to get rid of it in multiple ways like

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd@wl01.service
sudo systemctl disable wl01.service
sudo systemctl reset-failed
```

all of which hasn't fixed my problem, the first one comes back saying that there is no such file or directory. How can I get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: If service is really enabled, it should create a symbolic link under `/etc/systemd/system/`. Look there if you can find the version with typo. For example with 'find /etc/systemd/system -name w*.service`

Comment: Unfortunately not :/ Only 3 files: display-manager.service, getty.target.wants, multi-user.target.wants :/

Comment: those `.wants` shouldn't be files but folders which represent systemd targets (equivalent of init level in sysvinit, do look that up so you get a bit of background knowledge :) Obviously it should be in one of them. Thats why i was hinting with `find` command that searches recursively.

Answer (score 0):

The document in `man systemctl` explains that the `enable` commands makes symlinks and the `disable` commands removes them. It refers to the documentation for the `[Install]` section of unit files for more information.

`man systemd.unit` has some docs related to the `[Install]` section which provides an example of where a symlink is stored.  If the `[Install]` section contains `WantedBy=multi-user-.target`, then the symlink would be created in: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/foo.service`

*So, check the `[Install]` section in the the related dhcpcd service file, and then check that the related symlink has been deleted.*

Finally, as described in `man systemctl`, there is an even stronger version of `disable` called `mask` which prevents absolutely all forms of starting your service, so you can try that, too.